# Bootstrap-RTL Buttons don't work on mobile

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

On some of the mobile devices the bootstrap buttons don't respond(Galaxy S3,S4).

Here is the code:

```
<div class="text-center" style="padding-top:2em;">
<a class="btn btn-large btn-info" href="/cook_register/">some-rtl-text</a></div>
```

I tried all day long to fix this.Please help.

Comment: It is a bootstrap RTL bug for sure.

Comment: well i fixed it it, i was using alertify. it had an invisible container that displays the notifications, that sticks on android browsers, but it get removes automatically on all other browsers, but does not gets away on NAtive browser.